# azuresql connection string-user auth not admin

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, connection-string

The boilet plate connection string for sql azuredb uses the server's admin username/pwd. Using contained database a user can login to a specific db without needing server login access.

Can I setup the connection string of the database to the db user instead of having to use the server's admin user? I am using the connstring for an azure function to fetch data from db. Also, the user doesn't have an active directory account.

Thanks a bunch for your help

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to create a database user then you use the user to login the database. If so, you can do that. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins#non-administrator-users

Comment: Hi @JimXu yes I can create it, but instead of the connection string using the admin's username/pwd, can I use this user's login credentials for the connstring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use non-admin user to connect Azure SQL in Azure function, you can use the following connection string

```
Server=tcp:<sql server name>.database.windows.net,1433;
Initial Catalog=<databse name>;Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=<the non-adimn user name>;
Password=<passsword>;
MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

For example

1. use SSMS to create non-admin user fro the database you need

```
 CREATE USER jim WITH PASSWORD = '<strong_password>'
 ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER jim;
```

2. Code. I use `System.Data.SqlClient 4.6.1` to connect Azure sql in Azure function

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var constr = "Server=tcp:<sql server name>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<databse name>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<the non-adimn user name>;Password=<passsword>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                var sql = "SELECT * FROM StarWars";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            log.LogInformation(reader.GetString(2));
                        }
                    }
                }


            }

...

}
```

[image]

[image]

---

## update

If you want to use non-admin user to connect Azure SQL, please change the `User ID` value in the connecting string then save in application settings

1. Configure connection string

```
Server=tcp:<sql server name>.database.windows.net,1433;
Initial Catalog=<databse name>;Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=<the non-adimn user name>;
Password=<passsword>;
MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

2. Save in the application setting
   [image]
3. Get it with code
   [image]

Comment: thanks @Jimxu, not possible on a connection string to keep security then? Btw sorry unrelated but couldn't resist - I really enjoyed the Mandalorian, just finished watching it :)

Comment: @SergioSolorzano what do you mean ```not possible on a connection string to keep security then?```?

Comment: this post is trying to use the azuresql db's connection string (database->connstring) securely to communicate with azure's function: take azuresql db's connstring and paste that as a new Azure function App Setting to hide the connectionstring  from outside world (function ->configuration->application settings)

Comment: @SergioSolorzano You can save the connection string in the application settings. Then you can use code `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("setting name")` to read it : https://i.stack.imgur.com/64N0l.png.

Comment: yes but the username for the db connstring is fixed to the admin username in azure, so how to change it?

Comment: @SergioSolorzano Please see my update. Besides, could you please tell me what do you mean ```the username for the db connstring is fixed to the admin username in azure```?

Comment: Hi @JimXu I create a user that only has access to the db, not the serverdb (contained db). I want to connect from an azure function to the db using this userdb user, not the admin of the server and implicitly the db. When I pick up the connection string of the db created by Azure it has the admin's login details hardwired which I can't change. Hence I can't add to my function's Application Settings connection string the db user details to open a connection with the db because they won't match what's on the db->connection string created by azure. I hope that explains what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @SergioSolorzano when you copy the connecting string from Azure portal, you can change the username by yourself. Once  the user you use in the database,  your function can connect sql.

Comment: @SergioSolorzano You can change the username in the connecting string. it has no problem

Comment: that worked, I had messed up the user auth somehow, thanks a bunch!

Comment: the update was really helpful too to avoid credentials in the code :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict access to your SQL Database, you can also grant a Managed Identity to your function app, and grant access to it in the Sql Database. This way, only your function will be able to connect, and there's no risk of the connection string being leaked.

Here are good examples about how to do it:

https://www.azurecorner.com/using-managed-service-identity-in-azure-functions-to-access-azure-sql-database/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi

Comment: thank you @Thiago Custodio I've whitelisted the function app ip addresses on the db server but your suggestion is really neat !